# Make Images in UIImageView stay there despite of navigation

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview

I'm working on a services app in which a user makes a post. This process involves three view controllers.

> (Details VC) -> (Images Upload VC) -> (Post Preview VC)

But, once I upload images on second view controller and I navigate to the previous view controller, images disappear and I find all UIImageViews empty(no images).

How to make images stay there regardless of navigation?

Thanks

Comment: share some code .

Comment: Are the images being lost going from previewVC to uploadVC, or from detailsVC to uploadVC? If you want your images to not be deleted when moving between VC's you need to store references to them in a class separate from your VC hierarchy.

Comment: Spads, Images are on ImagesUploadVC and images are being lost while i navigate back to DetailsVC.